# Android - How to implement a 2 view vertical scroll screen

Tags: android

What do you think is the best way to implement the following: there are two views (A and B) and both should have the same height of the screen. View A should be on top of View B. View B is accessed by scrolling down on the screen (like a list view).

Would you use a vertical ViewPager, ListView, ScrollView, other?

Thank you

Comment: How do you mean: be accessed by scrollimg, if they are same size and A takes half of screen shouldn't B take other half of screen without scrolling?

Comment: Actually A and B will not be shown at the same time... It would be something similar to a viewpager, but vertically. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to stop showing half of both views use scrollview. If you want to switch between whole views use vertical pager. It really depends on what effect you want to achieve.

Comment: the effect would be something like the viewpager effect.. thanks!